# Have nginx return a 204 instead of 5xx

Tags: nginx

I need my nginx front-end to return 204 when the back-end reply a 5xx or timeout.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, finally I used:

```
location @return_204 {
    return  204;
}

location / {
        proxy_pass http://zzz;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 = @return_204;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) directive to achieve this. Not that you would also need to set [proxy_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) to make Nginx process the errors.

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 =204;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i followed your response but now i can see from access.log that nginx is returning **302**... :-/